# Is it true that all animals and plants could talk in Satya Yug? then why not in Kaliyuga?

Tags: kali-yuga, animals, life, plants

From Ramayana, we can know that there were some characters of monkeys or vanaras, Jambhavan, Hanuman etc associated with Lord Rama's job. Similarly like oceans and mountains, were also able to talk/feel.

Is it true that all animals and plants could talk in Satya Yug?

Then why in kaliyug they are not able to talk?

Comment: No, plants and animals still can converse. It is we humans who have lost the ability to understand and reciprocate to them.

Comment: you have contradicted yourself in your question. You say it is true because it is a mythological story - mythological means - by definition - false belief or idea...

Comment: "From this mythical story it is proved that animals were also talking" - No it doesn't prove they talk. Not all stories from Rāmāyaṇa (which is a kāvya/poem) are meant to be taken literally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Animal companions of Rama were not ordinary animals. They were specially created children of gods.

http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga17/bala_17_frame.htm

> When Vishnu attained the sonship of the great-souled king Dasharatha, then Brahma the self-created addressed all of the gods this way. [1-17-1]
>
> "Let mighty and guise changing helpmates be procreated to that truth abiding and valorous Vishnu who is the well-wisher of all of us. [1-17-2]
>
> "Let monkey-shaped progeny equalling Vishnu's valour be procreated from the physiques of prominent apsara-s and gandharva-s, from the girls of yaksha-s and pannaga-s, and also thus from the bodies of kinnaraa-s, she-vidyaadharaa-s, she-riksha-s and she-monkeys, and they shall be wizards of miracles and audacious ones, in travel they shall have air's speed, **bestowed with intellect they shall be the knowers of ideation**, and with their divine physique they shall be ineliminable, they shall be endowed with all the assaultive aspects of all missiles, and they shall be untiring in their efforts, like you who thrive on amrita, the ambrosia, unmindful of thirst and hunger. [1-17-3, 4, 5, 6]
>
> "I have already created the eminent bear Jambavanta in earlier times, as he suddenly came forth from my yawning face. [1-17-7]
>
> This is to say that Brahma has already created such a typical being, namely Jambavanta, prior to all the gods, as a role model in creation.
>
> Thus the gods have procreated many thousands of such valorous and guise changing monkeys who with their immeasurable strength and bravery are manifest for the elimination of the decahedral demon Ravana. [1-17-17b, 18a]
>
> And they with their elephantine, mountainous and prodigious bodies quickly took birth in bears, monkeys, sacred langoors. [1-17-18b, 19a]
>
> Some of the vanara-s endowed with superior valour are born to female langoors, and like that some more to female bears and kinnaraa-s. [1-17-20b, 21a]

Comment: Its's also mentioned in Shreemad Bhagvat Purana that plants are almost unconscious  they can feel the reactions from inside only but are not capable to respond. They are created as such from the begining by Brahma. Also try to add some ref. why one takes the rebirth  in the l owerr Yoni's like plant and animals (due to past karma to suffer by not being able to talk etc.) You can search garuda purana. And if you want , add the above  ref. in your  answer.Here is the link of Bhagvat purana. 
https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/10/20

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as per scriptures, in the Satayuga, animals, birds, beasts, and other living beings, could talk in the Divine Language.

Also, even the natural enemies were friendly with each other.

This is stated in the Skanda Mahā-Purāṇa.

> [Chapter 27](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc493310.html), Tīrtha-māhātmya, Nāgara-khaṇḍa
>
> अष्टाविंशतिसहस्राणि लक्षाः सप्तदशैव तु ।
> प्रमाणेन कृतं प्रोक्तं यत्र शुक्लो जनार्दनः ॥ १० ॥
>
> ...
>
> **तत्र सत्त्वाश्च ये केचित्पशवः पक्षिणो मृगाः । दैवीं वाचं प्रजल्पंति न
> विरोधं व्रजंति च** ॥ १५ ॥ क्रीडंति नकुलैः सर्पा बिडाला मूषकैः समम् ।
> पञ्चाननैर्मृगा नित्यमुलूकाश्चापि वायसैः ॥  १६ ॥ अकृष्टा च मही सस्यं
> जनयत्यति भूरिशः । व्रीहिमुद्गयवप्रायं सुस्वादु बलवृद्धिदम् ॥ १७ ॥
> सर्वर्तुफलिनो वृक्षाः सपुष्पफलधारिणः । सुपत्राः कंटकैर्हीनाः
> कल्पपादपसंनिभाः ॥ १८ ॥
>
> > 10. Kṛta Yuga is said to consist of seventeen lakh twenty-eight thousand years, when Janārdana remains white in colour, and Dharma has all its four feet intact.
>
> ...
>
> > 15. to 18. **All living beings, animals, birds and beasts speak the divine
> >     language.** They are not mutually inimical. **Serpents sport about along
> >     with mongooses, cats along with mice, deer with lions, and owls with
> >     crows.** Even without being cultivated, the earth (though not ploughed)
> >     produces much vegetation consisting of cereals, pulses, barleys etc.
> >     They are tasty and able to accord strength and nourishment. The trees
> >     bear fruits in all the seasons with excellent flowers and fruits, good
> >     leaves etc. They are devoid of thorns and they resemble Kalpa trees.
>
> English Translation by G.V. Tagare

`Then why in kaliyuga they are not able to talk?`

- Because each Yuga has it own Yuga dharma, and characteristics, which are sanctioned by the Supreme, and the cycle continues in the per-ordained or pre-determined ways only.

> [Chapter 11](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57236.html), Book 6, Devī Bhāgavatapurāṇa
>
> व्यास उवाच
>
> राजन् यस्मिन्युगे यादृक्प्रजा भवति कालतः । नान्यथा तद्‌भवेन्नूनं
> युगधर्मोऽत्र कारणम् ॥ ११ ॥
>
> > 11. Vyāsa said :-- O King! As the Yuga changes, so the people changes in course of time. Nothing can alter its course, for this is caused by
> >     the Yuga Dharma (the Dharma peculiar to each Yuga).
>
> English Translation by Swami Vijñanananda.

Comment: I love animals and this is wonderful  Thx for posting this answer Vivikta 